# How to create HLS token authentication

Tags: nginx, rtmp, http-live-streaming

I have nginx rtmp streaming server with token authentication and it works excellently, I use this code to the nginx.conf

```
application live {
   live on;
   on_play http://localhost:8080/on_play;
}
```

and

```
location /on_play {
   secure_link $arg_st,$arg_e;
   secure_link_md5 mysecretkey$arg_app/$arg_name$arg_e;

   if ($secure_link = "") {
       return 501;
   }
   if ($secure_link = "0") {
       return 502;
   }

   return 200;
}
```

I have second application hls:

```
application hls {
   allow play all;
   live on;
   hls on;
   hls_path /tmp/hls;
}
```

but on here "on_play" not working, how can I create hls token as for rtmp?

I have this url:

```
rtmp://{SERVER_IP}/live/channel1?***e=1453546548&st=-I2EcZJRXcarSjJaMRuNqA***
```

and it works but I'd like:

```
http://{SERVER_IP}/hls/channel1.m3u8?e=1453546548&st=-I2EcZJRXcarSjJaMRuNqA
```

or

```
http://{SERVER_IP}/hls/channel1.m3u8?token=unique_key_every_refresh
```

Can you help me how to create HLS secure url?